# How to get the XPath result without any commas or square brackets?

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

I have a code such as:

```
<out:a>
<out:Name Type="First" TypeCode="Best">JAE</out:Name>
<out:Name Type="Last" TypeCode="Best">ADAMS</out:Name>
</out:a>
```

When I gave the XPath expression as

```
(//*[local-name() = 'Name']/text())[1],(//*[local-name() = 'Name']/text())[2],
```

I got the result as [JAE,ADAMS]

How can I give the XPath expression so that I can the result as **JAE ADAMS**?

Comment: From your other questions I get the impression you are still learning XPath expressions. Have a look at this simple *starting* tutorial: http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear as to where you are using this XPath expression.

In most cases you could use something like:

```
concat(//*:Name[@Type='First'], " ", //*:Name[@Type='Last'])
```

In SoapUI XPath assertion, the concatenation is performed automatically, so just a simple:

```
${#Response#//*:Name[@Type='First']} ${#Response#//*:Name[@Type='Last'])}
```

(note the extra space) will work.

Comment: The answer with concat function works. Thank you. I'm using the xpath in SOAP UI. So I wanted to use the Datasource that will get the name from the database. So when I give the expected result as ${DataSource-Name#Name}, I'm getting error as XPathContains comparison failed for path [concat((//*[local-name() = 'Name']/text())[1], " ", (//*[local-name() = 'Name']/text())[2])], expecting [], actual was [JAE ADAMS]. How do I tweak the xpath expression now?

Comment: @IrineMathew I do not understand. Did you try the XPath expression I gave above? Exactly as given above?

Comment: This is the xpath expression i've given: concat((//*[local-name() = 'Name']/text())[1], " ", (//*[local-name() = 'Name']/text())[2]). And this is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly `string-join` will do. Try:

```
string-join( ((//*[local-name() = 'Name']/text())[1],(//*[local-name() = 'Name']/text())[2]), ' ' )
```

or

```
string-join( (//*[local-name() = 'Name']/text())[position() le 2], ' ' )
```

or

```
string-join( subsequence( //*[local-name() = 'Name']/text(), 1, 2), ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The commas and square brackets are a notation that indicates that the result is a node set or sequence.  You apparently would prefer a ***string***.

First, however, note that your XML is not well-formed; it uses an undeclared namespace prefix.  Here is your XML fixed to be well-formed:

```
<out:a xmlns:out="example.com/out">
  <out:Name Type="First" TypeCode="Best">JAE</out:Name>
  <out:Name Type="Last" TypeCode="Best">ADAMS</out:Name>
</out:a>
```

Then, any of these XPath expressions

- **XPath 1.0**

  ```
  concat(/*/*[1], ' ', /*/*[2])
  ```
- **XPath 1.0** (namespace-responsible)

  ```
  concat(//out:Name[1], ' ', //out:Name[2])
  ```
- **XPath 2.0**

  ```
  string-join(/*/*, ' ')
  ```
- **XPath 2.0**

  ```
  string-join(normalize-space(), ' ')
  ```

Will yield the ***string***

```
JAE ADAMS
```

you request.