# How can I get the texts by calling the attribute?

Tags: xpath, soapui

I have a code such as

```
<out:Names>
<out:Name Type="First" TypeCode="Best">JAE</out:Name>
<out:Name Type="Last" TypeCode="Best">ADAMS</out:Name>
</out:Names>
<out:Address>
<out:AddressLine Order="1" TypeCode="Best">33877 810TH AVE</out:AddressLine>
<out:City>GADSDEN</out:City>
</out:Address>
<out:Names>
<out:Name Type="First" TypeCode="Best">KATHY</out:Name>
<out:Name Type="Last" TypeCode="Best">GREEN</out:Name>
</out:Names>
<out:Address>
<out:AddressLine Order="1" TypeCode="Best">5th GARRISON AVE</out:AddressLine>
<out:City>Jersey City</out:City>
</out:Address>
```

How can I give the XPath expression in SOAPUI PRO so that I can get the result of all the first names/last names?

Comment: Please show a complete sample of the XML document that includes a _namespace declaration_ for the `out:` prefix.

Comment: Irine Mathew, I believe that you posted [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754733/how-to-get-the-xpath-result-without-any-commas-or-square-brackets) earlier and it was answered. So,  **can you edit the question and clarify** how you are using it(in which step) and what you are trying to achieve? Because, if you are doing xpath, it may say `more than one in the result` some thing like that. It is difficult unless you say how it is going to be used.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide a [mcve]?